# Can I convert an HTML comment to actual HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, documentfragment

If I insert a comment node into a document fragment, can I convert it to HTML later? Example:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
var comment = document.createComment('<div>Testing</div>');

fragment.appendChild(comment);

// Convert comment into actual HTML?
```

What this would look like inside of a fragment:

```
<!--<div>Testing</div>-->
```

And how it should be when done (actual DOM):

```
<div>Testing</div>
```

---

***Background:***

There are many limitations for inserting HTML into a fragment. Fragments don't support `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML` etc. There are other methods for getting HTML into fragments, but they drop certain elements and leave only the inner text. For example, creating a fragment with the `createRange` API drops those types of nodes and I will be left with a fragment with just the text node "Data"

```
var fragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment('<td>Data</td>');
```

The hope is that if I can convert a comment into actual DOM, that it will work as expected.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use a fragment?

Comment: Yes, I am taking the results of a templating engine (resulting html), adding it to a fragment, attaching events in the fragment, and then appending that fragment to the DOM in one move. This way, I can stay out of the UI for as long as possible.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Not really clear what you are trying to do.  Comment nodes have nodeType==9. But must be html comment

Comment: Why store it in a comment? Surely the content you are manipulating is the exact opposite of a template?

Comment: @symcbean, the HTML comes from a template. As an example, think of the resulting HTML from a handlebars template. The templating engine I am working with returns the resulting HTML. And I am trying to figure out how to get it into a fragment without losing nodes if some of those first childnodes are things like `<td>` or `<option>`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No. Still not clear if what you are describing is a template or variant content, and still not clear why you are defering its parsing, and still not clear why you think a commemt is inany way suitable for delivering the content to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your underlying problem is that you need to stuff HTML text into a `DocumentFragment`, so here is a helper function to do so for you.

```js
var container = document.createElement('div')

function createFragmentWithHTML (html, doc) {
  var result = (doc || document).createDocumentFragment()
  container.innerHTML = html
  while (container.firstChild) result.appendChild(container.firstChild)
  return result
}


var fragment = createFragmentWithHTML('<div>Testing</div><p><strong>More text</strong></p>')

// do whatever you want with `fragment`
document.body.appendChild(fragment)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the entire body you can use that snippet:

```js
 var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    bodyHtml = body.innerHTML;
 while (bodyHtml.indexOf("<!--") !== -1) { // will replace all the comments with empty string
    bodyHtml = bodyHtml.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", ""); 
 }
 body.innerHTML = bodyHtml;
```

```html
Hello
<h1>hi</h1>

<!--<div>Testing</div>-->
<!--<div>Testing</div>-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would do the trick

```
 var element = document.getElementById("whatever"); // get the parent element
 var comment = element.innerHTML; // get the thml
 var html = comment.replace("<!--", "").replace("-->", ""); // remove the comment
 element.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 1):

Text content of an HTML comment can be accessed via the `nodeValue` property of the [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node) interface or the `data` property of the [`CharacterData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData) interface that the HTML [`Comment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment) interface inherits from:

```html
<!--<div>Example</div>-->
```

```js
var code = comment.data; /* Now contains `<div>Example</div>` text */
var code = comment.nodeValue; // Same result.
```

Fwiw, I have a blog [post](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2009/05/html-comment-as-data-container/) about using HTML comment as data container.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your comments with `element.childNodes` method, then use `textContent` method to get the content of comment, then change it into HTML Element with `innerHTML` method, then remove the comment node and replace it with Element Node.

```js
parseComments('container');

function parseComments(getContainerId){
 var container = document.getElementById(getContainerId);
 var nodes = container.childNodes;
 for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++){
  if(nodes[i].nodeType===8){
   var virtualCont = document.createElement('DIV');
   var getContent = nodes[i].textContent;
   virtualCont.innerHTML = getContent;
   container.removeChild(nodes[i]);
   if(nodes[i+1]){
    container.insertBefore(virtualCont.children[0],nodes[i+1]);
   } else {
    container.appendChild(virtualCont.children[0]);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>some header A</h1>
  <!--<p>some hidden content A</p>-->
  <p>some content</p>
  <!--<p>some hidden content B</p>-->
  <p>another content</p>
  <!--<h1>some hidden header B</h1>-->
  <!--<p>another hidden content C</p>-->
</div>
```